# Using Angular's `useExitsing` with custom form validations?

Tags: javascript, angular

Reading Angular's docs regarding [*adding custom validators to template-driven forms*](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms)
— There is a a simple example there for *custom* validating an input with :

- required
- minlength="4"
- value should not contain "bob"

Markup :

```
<input id="name" name="name" 
       required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
       [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

Directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenName]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ForbiddenValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
   ...
  }
}
```

The  code is pretty clear. *But* they also say there :

> You may have noticed that the custom validation directive is
>   instantiated with `useExisting` rather than `useClass`. The registered
>   validator must be this instance of the `ForbiddenValidatorDirective`—the
>   instance in the form with its `forbiddenName` property bound to “`bob`".
>   If you were to replace `useExisting` with `useClass`, then you’d be
>   registering a new class instance, one that doesn’t have a
>   `forbiddenName`.

Now — *I do know* what is the difference between `useExistsing` and `useValue`.

But which existing instance are they talking about ? if `useExistsing` doesn't find a match , it will create one ...so?

Also, how does registering a new class instance will not have the `forbiddenName` ? it is a property within it !

**Question:**

I don't understand what is the *sequence of operations* that occur here.
Who is creating the first instance to be later be used by the directive code with useExisting ?

*( in a way that If I use `useClass` instead  , it will create another instance which doesn't contain the property....(???))*

[**The  online demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pkkwj?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Where you getting the problem? Is it in Unit testing?

Comment: @ramesh no. I just don't understand to which existing provider which already has the property, do they mean. I dont see what's going on here via flow of operations  pov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` instance will only be created while it is used in your components. `useExisting` will only make sure to use the exact instance
which keeps the `@Input` field.

> I don't understand what is the sequence of operations that occur here.

1. A instance of `ForbiddenValidatorDirective`(with `@Input` field) is created while Angular detected `appForbiddenName` is used in your component.
2. Angular trying to inject `NG_VALIDATORS` while creating instance of `form` directive(form directive detected).

> in a way that If I use useClass instead , it will create another instance which doesn't contain the property....(???)

For `useClass`, Angular will just consider `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` as a normal class and create a instance by `new ForbiddenValidatorDirective()` while `@Input` will be ignored here.

---

While understanding `useExisting` of provider **NG_VALIDATORS**, we should look for the place where it is injected, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L99) first.

The `NG_VALIDATORS` is injected at `form` directive in order to be invoked while doing validations of the form. Just as stated below, here you must use `useExisting` in order to get `forbiddenName` **which only exist on the instance created where the directive is used**, otherwise `@Input` filed will be undefined.

> The registered
>   validator must be this instance of the `ForbiddenValidatorDirective`—the
>   instance in the form with its `forbiddenName` property bound to “`bob`".
>   If you were to replace `useExisting` with `useClass`, then you’d be
>   registering a new class instance, one that doesn’t have a
>   `forbiddenName`.

Comment: This answer contains cites parts from question...(imho). It still doesnt explain the flow.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have add some details about your question, hope it will help. :-) BTW, I would recommend you put some breakpoints in `angular` packages to help understanding those problems. :-)

Comment: Oh this is the missing part which i've missed : _will only be created while it is used in your components_ . so it's not like a service where it's created when injected , but it is created when first met in markup , Right ???

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, directive has the same life cycle with component.